# Canon EDSDK on .NET Core 6 standard 2022 C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, dllimport, .net-standard, canon-sdk

Is it possible to control a [Canon Camera](https://asia.canon/en/campaign/developerresources/sdk#digital-camera-ed-sdk-v13-15-10) on the latest .NET, currently .NET 6, or Core or Standard using their EDSDK.dll version 13.15.10.3 **or any other lib** via C#?

Control = snap a pic, save the image, set some settings, etc.

Canon provides a SDK [EDSDK.dll](https://en.canon-cna.com/pro/stories/eos-digital-sdk-explained/) and example C# code circa .NET 4.5 (2012). Current dll version is 13.15.10.3.

In framework the example app **works** and uses [DllImport("EDSDK.dll")]

The same code and lib on .NET 6 throws this error:

> System.BadImageFormatException   HResult=0x8007000B   Message=An
> attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
> (0x8007000B)   Source=HardwareControl
> StackTrace:
> at EDSDKLib.EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK()

Any info to how this would be done with the latest tools OR a strong 'noop, move on' is appreciated.Thanks!

/rant: MS basically pulled a 'New Coke' over .NET versions so [here](https://code-maze.com/differences-between-net-framework-net-core-and-net-standard/) is a random primer.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using x86 or explicitly using x64 for the runtime? I *suspect* that's the problem (and my guess is that you want x86).

Comment: @JonSkeet it worked on x86! You have too much knowledge for one mind :) Thank you!

Comment: @TheDev6 hi, can you send me a link please to a working project of yours for the camera control ? i have eos 550d and i can't make it work and i'm trying for hours with the dll's and getting exception.  please help me.

Comment: @EliotShein Unfortunately Canon makes you sign up for the sdk and samples. But EDSDKLib.EDSDK.EdsInitializeSDK(); is the line that will blow up if your dll is not found, or x86/x64 is not set on the class lib to the corresponding target of the dlls.